# How to trigger child hover style on hovering parent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a List in reactjs. I want to enlarge only the content of listitem (Avatar and Listitemtext) when the Listitem is hovered. Here is my code...

```html
<List>
          <ListItem button className={classes.list}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
             <i className="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
            </Avatar>
            <ListItemText classes={{subheading:classes.subheading,secondary:classes.secondary}}
              primary="All " secondary="100 People" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
              <i className="fa fa-fire" ></i>
            </Avatar>
            <ListItemText classes={{subheading:classes.subheading,secondary:classes.secondary}} primary="Trending" secondary="31 Stars" />
          </ListItem>
          <li>
            <Divider inset />
          </li>
</List>
```

**Class Definitions**

```js
list:{
  '&:hover .inner':{
   transform:'scale(1.2)',
   boxShadow:'2px 2px 4px 2px #9e9e9e',
   
   color:'#e65100',
  },
 },
 avatar:{
  backgroundColor:'#d51e',
  display:'flex',
  '&:hover':{
   transform:'scale(1.2)',
   boxShadow:'2px 2px 4px 2px #9e9e9e',
  },
 },
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I would love to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the CSS `:hover` selector to whatever component you want to hover. Here's how you should define the `:hover` style:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  enlargeOnHover: {
    '&:hover':{
        transform:'scale(1.2)',
        boxShadow:'2px 2px 4px 2px #9e9e9e',
        color:'#e65100',
    },
  },
});
```

## Hover individual pieces of content inside the `ListItem`

You can apply it to pieces of content inside a `ListItem` like this:

```
<ListItem button>
  <Avatar className={classes.enlargeOnHover}>A</Avatar>
  <ListItemText primary="Inbox" className={classes.enlargeOnHover}/>
</ListItem>
```

Note that since there's quite a bit of padding inside the `ListItem`, you're going to need to really hover directly on top of the content (directly over the text or the avatar) to see the style in action.

## Hover the whole `ListItem`

You can also apply it to the entire `ListItem` like this:

```
<List>
  <ListItem button className={classes.enlargeOnHover}>
    <Avatar>
      <i className="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </Avatar>
    <ListItemText primary="All" secondary="100 People" />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem button className={classes.enlargeOnHover}>
    <Avatar>
      <i className="fa fa-fire" ></i>
    </Avatar>
    <ListItemText primary="Trending" secondary="31 Stars" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: Nope,it won't work. Because it will apply the hovered style to the ListItem. I want only the avatar and Listitemtext to change its style on hovered.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now the hover only kicks in for individual elements inside the `ListItem`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Well if you don't mind sharing your solution as an answer to this question, I'd like to see it. I'm curious what you were aiming for really.